# SQL Server White Papers vs Books Online - What's the difference and where are the white papers?

Tags: sql-server

I've heard people reference white papers.  After doing a preliminary search for SQL-Server white papers, there are various sites with random pdfs.  I'm looking or white papers that will help me gain a deeper knowledge of SQL Server.

How are white papers different from books online?  Are white papers just a deeper dive into a technical issue?

Does Microsoft have an organized place for white papers? If so, where please?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: VTC, but my *first* search result returned a [gallery of white papers](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13146.white-paper-gallery-for-sql-server.aspx) hosted on TechNet. Books online is the old term for what is basically just SQL Server documentation. White papers are [white papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_paper), not documentation.

Comment: I saw that too on my search, but nothing on that link after SQL Server 2014.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How are white papers different from books online? Are white papers
>   just a deeper dive into a technical issue?

Books Online is the documentation, while [white papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_paper) are often more technical discussions of a topic, some times with an lean toward marketing.

> Does Microsoft have an organized place for white papers? If so, where
>   please?

Microsoft has an gallery of SQL white papers up through SQL Server 2014 here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13146.white-paper-gallery-for-sql-server.aspx

White papers for SQL 2017 and 2019 are here: https://info.microsoft.com/sql-server-2017-technical-white-paper-registration.html and https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-SQLDB-Microsoft-SQL-Server-WhitePaper.html

An SQL 2019 white paper focusing on big data is here: https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-SQL-Server-2019-Big-Data-WhitePaper.html

More can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=white+paper+sql